Rails Associated Child Model
I am trying to follow the rails getting started guide to set up my project, but am running into an issue with setting up the nested models/controllers/views.
I have Activity model and Refusal model, refusals are only on an Activity. Similar to Article and comments from the guide. I have tried to set it up similarly, but am getting an error with displaying the refusal partial.
Models
class Activity < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :section

  enum :status, [:incomplete, :self_complete, :approval_pending, :complete]
  enum :activity_type, [:construction, :dossier, :warranty, :custom]

  has_many :refusals, dependent: :destroy
end
class Refusal < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :activity

  enum :reason, [:not_complete, :inadequate_proof, :other]
end

Activity Controller
class ActivitiesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_activity, only: %i[ show edit update destroy ]

  # GET /activities or /activities.json
  def index
    @activities = Activity.all
  end

  # GET /activities/1 or /activities/1.json
  def show
    @refusals = @activity.refusals.build
  end

  # GET /activities/new
  def new
    @activity = Activity.new
  end

  # GET /activities/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /activities or /activities.json
  def create
    @activity = Activity.new(activity_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @activity.save
        format.html { redirect_to activity_url(@activity), notice: "Activity was successfully created." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @activity }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @activity.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
.
.
.
end

Refusals Controller
class RefusalsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_refusal, only: %i[ show edit update destroy ]

  # GET /refusals or /refusals.json
  def index
    @refusals = Refusal.all
  end

  # GET /refusals/1 or /refusals/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /refusals/new
  def new
    @refusal = Refusal.new
  end

  # GET /refusals/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /refusals or /refusals.json
  def create
    @activity = Activity.find(params[:activity_id])
    @refusal = @activity.refusals.new(refusal_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @refusal.save
        format.html { redirect_to refusal_url(@refusal), notice: "Refusal was successfully created." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @refusal }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @refusal.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
    redirect_to article_path(@article)
  end
.
.
.
end

Activity Show View
<div class="mx-auto md:w-2/3 w-full flex">
  <div class="mx-auto">
    <% if notice.present? %>
      <p class="py-2 px-3 bg-green-50 mb-5 text-green-500 font-medium rounded-lg inline-block" id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
    <% end %>

    <%= render @activity %>
    <p class="my-5">
    <strong class="block font-medium mb-1">Refusals:</strong>
  </p>
  <%= render @activity.refusals%>
  <p class="my-5">add refusal</p>
  <%= render 'refusals/form', refusal: @refusal%>
.
.   
.  
</div>
</div>

Refusal partial _refusal.html.erb
<div id="<%= dom_id refusal %>">
  <p class="my-5">
    <strong class="block font-medium mb-1">Activity:</strong>
    <%= refusal.activity_id %>
  </p>

  <p class="my-5">
    <strong class="block font-medium mb-1">Reason:</strong>
    <%= refusal.reason.humanize %>
  </p>

  <p class="my-5">
    <strong class="block font-medium mb-1">Description:</strong>
    <%= refusal.description %>
  </p>

  <p class="my-5">
    <strong class="block font-medium mb-1">Refuser:</strong>
    <%= refusal.refuser %>
  </p>

</div>

With this in place when trying to view an Activity. I get an error undefined method humanize' for nil. I'm not exactly clear on how the <%= render @activity.refusals%>` part works, but shouldn't it only try to render the partial if there is a refusal attached? I checked in the console and there is a refusal for the activity I was trying to pull up, but it has a refusal reason, so shouldn't it be able to humanize the value?
#<Refusal:0x00000001223967c8
  id: 980190962,
  activity_id: 980190962,
  reason: "inadequate_proof",
  description: "MyString",
  refuser: "MyString",
  created_at: Mon, 03 Jun 2024 01:01:06.074415000 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Mon, 03 Jun 2024 01:01:06.074415000 UTC +00:00>]

I have mostly just used rails g scaffold to make all the code so far, it would be great if there were a rails-7 example project just using the default rails generators that I could see how things are tweaked and poke around in if you know of one.

You have a simple plurialization error. You're setting @refusals in ActivitiesController#show but you're passing @refusal in the view.
class ActivitiesController < ApplicationController
  
  # ....

  # GET /activities/1 or /activities/1.json
  def show
    # this was @refusals
    @refusal = @activity.refusals.build
  end

  # ...
end

And a swath of other problems. For example in your RefusalsController#create method you're trying to redirect after you have already sent a response.
If you're learning Rails I wouldn't recommend that you use the scaffolds. While they are great for rapid prototyping you quickly outrun your test coverage and they do not generate code for nested resources so you have to extensively rewrite the generated code anyways.

Thank you for linking that guide, I was able to resolve my issues related to the nested routes. You are right in that scaffolding can sometimes add too much boilerplate for at least a beginner to know all the places that need to be tweaked right off the bat. Thanks again for your help on this and my other questions!

It turns out that I had to deal with a few sections of boiler plate from the scaffold process, and I implemented [shallow nesting][1], then:

In the refusals show.html.erb, update the back link to go back to the Activities index page:
<%= link_to "Back to activities", activities_path,
In the refusals controller, find the activity on which to create and then use that to create:

# POST /refusals or /refusals.json
  def create
    @activity = Activity.find(params[:activity_id])
    @refusal = @activity.refusals.new(refusal_params)


In activities controller, pass in the refusals for the activity to the show view:

def show
    @refusal = @activity.refusals
  end


In the Activity show.html.erb add the following renders for the _refusal and refusals/form:

<%= render @activity.refusals %>
  <p class="my-5">add refusal</p>
  <%= render 'refusals/form'%>


In refusals form update the model being used to show the nested relationship, and name the intialize the refusal object given the new model declaration:
<%= form_with(model: [@activity, refusal = @activity.refusals.build], class: "contents") do |form| %>
[1]: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#shallow-nesting


That's still not quite right. If you want to show a list of on the show view that you should assign @refusals = @activity.refusals - avoid DB queries in the view. Ideally you would also assign @refusal = @activity.refusals.new instead of doing it in the view.

@max I may be misreading, but am I not settings @refusals = @activity.refusals in  controller in part 3 of my solution? Should this not be the case? The view I have is just to loop over all the refusals for the activity @activity.refusals (from here)[https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#rendering-partial-collections]
